# Cannot see my Asus Nexus 7 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, adb, nexus-7

I am working off my laptop at the moment and connected my nexus 7 via usb. For some reason I cannot see my nexus 7 in the eclipse ide. I tried installing drivers but to no avail. There is a yellow exclamation point beside the device in device manager.

Does anyone know what driver I need specifically in order to be able to debug on my laptop. Also I have already enabled the device for debugging and also have it connected as the PTP device.

Answer (score 3):

1. Plug in the Nexus 7
2. Go to "Device Manager" -> "Other Devices" -> Right Click over the yellow exclamation mark -> "Upate Drivers" -> "Let me choose" -> "Let me pick form device drivers on my computer"
3. Go to "SAMSUNG Android Phone" -> "Android ADB Interface" -> Next

Comment: "Device Manager" in what program ?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi in Windows

Answer (score 1):

Download Nexus USB Driver from this [Link](http://www.asus.com/Tablets_Mobile/Nexus_7/#support_Download_32)

And then proceed in @John Betts answer but choose the place of the downloaded and extracted folder

Answer (score 0):

A yellow exclamation point beside the device in device manager means your USB driver failed to start. I'd uninstall existing driver, and use the latest one from Eclipse ADT. Also, make sure you are using the right driver for your OS (32bit vs 64bit).